# PHP MYSQL - UPDATE user profile with SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, session, profile

I'm trying to update user profile with session. Suppose, the user profile page will update accordingly to the profile of the logged in user. Here's the sample code of user_profile.php:-

```
<?php
 session_start(); 
 ob_start();

 include("../function/dbconnect.php");
 include("header.php");
?>

<html>
<body>

<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['VALID_USER'])){

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $s=mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_staffs SET username='$username', password='$password' WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["VALID_USER"])."'");

    if ($s)
        { echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successful - Record Updated!'); window.location.href = 'user_profile.php';</script>"; }
    else
        { echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Unsuccessful - ERROR!'); window.location.href = 'user_profile.php';</script>"; }
}

$query1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_staffs WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["VALID_USER"])."'  AND user_levels = '".mysql_real_escape_string('1')."'");
$query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1); 

?>

<form  action="user_profile.php" method="POST">
<div>Your  Profile</div>
<table  border="0"  align="center"  cellpadding="2"  cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><div>Username:</div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="username" value="<?php  echo $query2['username'];  ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div  align="left"  id="tb-name">Password:</div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="password" value="<?php  echo $query2['password'];  ?>" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />
</form>

<?php
//  close  while  loop
}}
?>

<?php
//  close  connection;
mysql_close();
?>
</br>

</body>
</html>
```

The page returns blank. There are several other codes that I'm working on for the user_profile.php page too but, the results that I get are the same... I used below codes for admin to update user profile.

```
include('function/dbconnect.php');
        if(isset($_GET['id']))
        {
            $id=$_GET['id'];
                if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                {
                    $username   = $_POST['username'];
                    $email      = $_POST['email'];
                    $password   = $_POST['password'];
                    $user_type  = $_POST['user_type'];
                    $query3     = mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_staffs
                                              SET username='$username', email='$email', password='$password', WHERE id='$id'");

                    if ($query3)
                        { echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successful - Record Updated!'); window.location.href = 'user_list.php';</script>"; }
                    else
                        { echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Unsuccessful - ERROR!'); window.location.href = 'user_list.php';</script>"; }
                }

    $query1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_staffs WHERE id='$id'");
    $query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1); 



 <form method="post">
 <tr>
    <td><b>Username:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="username" style="width:255px" value="<?php echo $query2['username']; ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Email:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="email" style="width:255px" value="<?php echo $query2['email']; ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Password:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="password" style="width:255px" value="<?php echo $query2['password']; ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="right">
    <br />
        <span title="Click to update the user details"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" /></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>

  </form>
  <?php
    }
  ?>
```

Apparently, it works fine as it is. Though, when I tried to imply the codes for user so that they can update their own profile, the codes won't work. Where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Multiple important errors here: 1. Using deprecated `mysql_*` libraries; 2. Open to SQL Injection attacks; 3. Many HTML issues. Please rewrite your codes.

Comment: so why do you only sanitize the values in the `WHERE` and not what you are actually inserting?

Comment: Once your user changes their `username`, you never reset `$_SESSION['VALID_USER']` to that new value, so when you do the `SELECT` it will try to find the old `username` value and not the new value.

Comment: You have 1 too many `}` at `<?php //  close  while  loop }} ?>`. It should only be 1. The 2nd one will cause a fatal error, which is why your page is blank. If you turned on error reporting, or used an IDE it would have told you.

Comment: side note - `</br>` should be `<br>` or `<br />`, not `</br>`.

Comment: I guess, there are too many things that I overlooked and I sincerely apologize on that matter. I will reexamine and run through my codes again, and I will get back to you guys. Much thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

first check your session is exist or not and then replace ".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["VALID_USER"])." in your query by a variable like

```
$VALID_USER=mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["VALID_USER"]);


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$username = $_POST['username'];

$password = $_POST['password'];

$s=mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_staffs SET username='$username', password='$password' WHERE username='$VALID_USER");

if ($s)
    { echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successful - Record Updated!'); window.location.href = 'user_profile.php';</script>"; }
else
    { echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Unsuccessful - ERROR!'); window.location.href = 'user_profile.php';</script>"; }
}

 $query1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_staffs WHERE username='$'  AND user_levels = '".mysql_real_escape_string('1')."'");
$query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1);
```